# Message size when calling a WebService (WCF) from desktop application (.Net 2)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I've got a Web Service (WCF) which stores received files in the database.
When I call it from a .NET 4.5 web application I just specify in client's Web.config file:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_NameOfWS"  
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

So the client is allowed to send big files.

When I try to call it from my .NET 2 desktop application (yes, .NET 2) I receive the error:

```
HTTP 413: Request Entity Too Large
```

But I've got no Web.config file to configure as it's not a web application.

My app.config looks like:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <NameOfProject.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="NameOfProject_NameOfWebReference_NameOfWS"
            serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://myURL/NameOfWS.svc</value>
        </setting>
    </NameOfProject.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

And the NameOfWS.wsdl file has no maxBufferSize or maxReceivedMessageSize parameter.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Done, didn't know this policy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

If anybody needs to solve an issue like this, I post how I could make it work.

**Web.config in my service project**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyWCFInterface"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MyProject.MyWCFClass" >
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyWCFInterface"
                  contract="MyProject.MyWCFInterface"/>
      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**App.config in my client project**

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyWCFInterface" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:myPort/MyService.svc" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyWCFInterface" 
              contract="NameOfCreatedService.MyWCFInterface" 
              name="BasicHttpBinding_MyWCFInterface" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And what I didn't know and have been the final step, is **copy this App.config configuration in App.config of the main project of my client's solution**, if not the configuration isn't load at the startup and doesn't work the message size configuration.

I hope it can help anybody.

Thanks for the ones who have spent some time with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For app.config binding configuration example

A few of these methods please try;

```
 <binding name="bindingName" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I've just seen that BasicHttpBinding works just since .Net 3.0...

Answer (score 0):

write this on your **.net 2 app.config** it must be receive file but i suggest you copy **.net 4 app.config**  tag to **.net 2 app.config** it must work

```html
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
        <readerQuotas ... />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I've tried this config but it doesn't work, I've just seen that BasicHttpBinding works since .Net 3.0 :(